# JOIN BY Company Big SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query with 3 selects join by "UNION", from Vehicles, Drivers and Company.

```
select * from 
(
    (
    select 
        department as "Delegación",
        company as Compañía,
        0 as "% Docs. Empresa",
        count(distinct idClientTruck) as Vehículos,
        round(sum(ko)/(docs*count(distinct idClientTruck))*100) as "% Docs. Vehículos",
        0 as Conductores,
        0 as "% Docs. Conductores"
        from
        (
            select  
                cd.name as department,
                c.businessname as company, 
                (select count(*) from widoc_config where idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and idstatus=71001 and required=true) as docs, 
                wv.idClientTruck as idClientTruck, 
                cfg.idwidocconfig as idWidocConfig, 
                cfg.iddocument as idDocument, 
                a.idstatus as idStatus, 
                if(a.idstatus=43002,"0","1") as ko 
            from
                widoc_config_group cfg_g
                join widoc_config cfg on cfg.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and cfg.idstatus=71001 and cfg.required=true
                join widoc_client wc on wc.idclient=cfg_g.idclient and wc.idstatus=71001
                join client c on c.idclient=wc.idclientassociated and c.idstatus_client=5004
                join widoc_vehicle wv on wv.idwidocclient=wc.idwidocclient and wv.idstatus=71001
                join client_truck t on t.idclient_truck=wv.idclienttruck and t.idstatus_truckpart=33005
                join widoc_fulfill_vehicle fv on fv.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and fv.idwidocvehicle=wv.idwidocvehicle
                left join attachment_group a on a.idclient=wc.idclientAssociated and a.iddocument=cfg.iddocument and a.idstatus!=43004 and a.idFK=wv.idClientTruck
                left join client_department cd on cd.idClientDepartment=wc.idClientDepartment and cd.idStatus=71001
            where
                cfg_g.idclient = 3683
                #wc.idclientAssociated = 3683
                and cfg_g.identitytype=73004
                and cfg_g.idstatus=71001
        )
        v group by department,company
    )
    a UNION

    (
    select 
        department as "Delegación",
        company as Compañía,
        0 as "% Docs. Empresa",
        0 as Vehículos,
        0 as "% Docs. Vehículos",
        count(distinct idDriver) as Conductores,
        round(sum(ko)/(docs*count(distinct idDriver))*100) as "% Docs. Conductores"
        from
        (
            select 
                cd.name as department,
                c.businessname as company, 
                (select count(*) from widoc_config where idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and idstatus=71001 and required=true) as docs, 
                wd.idDriver as idDriver, 
                cfg.idwidocconfig as idWidocConfig, 
                cfg.iddocument as idDocument, 
                a.idstatus as idStatus, 
                if(a.idstatus=43002,"0","1") as ko
            from 
                widoc_config_group cfg_g
                join widoc_config cfg on cfg.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and cfg.idstatus=71001 and cfg.required=true
                join widoc_client wc on wc.idclient=cfg_g.idclient and wc.idstatus=71001
                join client c on c.idclient=wc.idclientassociated and c.idstatus_client=5004
                join widoc_driver wd on wd.idwidocclient=wc.idwidocclient and wd.idstatus=71001
                join driver d on d.iddriver=wd.iddriver and d.idstatus=71001
                join widoc_fulfill_driver fd on fd.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and fd.idwidocdriver=wd.idwidocdriver
                left join attachment_group a on a.idclient=wc.idclientAssociated and a.iddocument=cfg.iddocument and a.idstatus!=43004 and a.idFK=wd.idDriver
                left join client_department cd on cd.idClientDepartment=wc.idClientDepartment and cd.idStatus=71001
            where
                cfg_g.idclient = 3683
                #wc.idclientAssociated = 1865
                and cfg_g.identitytype=73003
                and cfg_g.idstatus=71001
        )
        x group by department,company 
    ) 
    b UNION 

    (
    select 
        department as "Delegación",
        company as Compañía,
        round(sum(ko)/docs*100) as "% Docs. Empresa",
        0 as Vehículos,
        0 as "% Docs. Vehículos",
        0 as Conductores,
        0 as "% Docs. Conductores"
        from
        (
            select 
                cd.name as department, 
                c.businessname as company, 
                (select count(*) from widoc_config where idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and idstatus=71001 and required=true) as docs, 
                cfg.idwidocconfig, 
                a.idstatus, 
                if(a.idstatus=43002,"0","1") as ko
            from
                widoc_config_group cfg_g
                join widoc_config cfg on cfg.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup and cfg.idstatus=71001 and cfg.required=true
                join widoc_client wc on wc.idclient=cfg_g.idclient and wc.idstatus=71001
                join client c on c.idclient=wc.idclientassociated and c.idstatus_client=5004
                join widoc_fulfill_client fc on fc.idwidocclient=wc.idwidocclient and fc.idwidocconfiggroup=cfg_g.idwidocconfiggroup
                left join attachment_group a on a.idclient=c.idclient and a.iddocument=cfg.iddocument and a.idstatus!=43004
                left join client_department cd on cd.idClientDepartment=wc.idClientDepartment and cd.idStatus=71001
              #    join attachment_doc d on d.idattachmentgroup=a.idattachmentgroup and d.idstatus!=43004
            where
                cfg_g.idclient = 3683
                and cfg_g.identitytype=73002
                and cfg_g.idstatus=71001
        ) t
        group by department,company
    )  
    c
);
```

What happens is that it repeats the same company for each select, like:

Company X -->  0 drivers  0 docs.Empresa   5 vehicles

Company X -->  4 drivers  0 docs.Empresa   0 vehicles

Company X -->  0 drivers  9 docs.Empresa   0 vehicles

What I need is that when a Company pops, all registers get at the same row, i don't know if i explained myself.

Company X -->  4 drivers  9 docs.Empresa   5 vehicles

Edit: I did a select * from this query, but the parenthesis at "b union" gives me this error: Syntax error: missing 'closing parenthesis'.

Comment: You don't explain yourself. Start with something simpler, and see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Well, you probably have to do a group by - possibly by placing the entire query into a subquery and doing the group by in the outer query. But it is a bit difficult to tell.